# Best way to place icons on a circle

Tags: ios, uiview

I want to place some menu icons on a circle so that it almost looks like a clock. Depending on the amount of icons, the space between them may vary. Whats the best way to put each of these icons in the form of a circle?

Comment: Tried. What have you?

Comment: I managed to do it but depending on the amount of icons I want to place, the layout is always different. How can I put the first icon always on the top of the circle and start from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematics.

If you know how many items you have then you can find the angle between them because you know there are 360 degrees (2pi radians) in a circle. Choose a start point and then use

```
x = centerX + r * cos(angle)
y = centerY + r * sin(angle)
```

Using the center point of the circle, the radius and the angle (in radians), increasing the angle for each item.